# Laravel: Calling paginate() inside a blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have access to a collection called `$files` inside my blade.  I am paginating and setting it to `$allFiles`.

`<?php $allFiles = $files->paginate(12); ?>`

In the blade beneath that, when I call:

```
<div>
   {{ $allFiles->links() }}
</div>
```

, I am getting the error `call to a member function links() on array`.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

---

EDIT: Adding more info and show what `$allFiles` is.  I logged it in my code and add that below:

```
Object
(
    [collection:protected] => App\Models\Collection Object
        (
            [connection:protected] => data
            [table:protected] => collections
            [timestamps] => 1
            [fillable:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title
                    [1] => content
                )

            [casts:protected] => Array
                (
                    [smart_collection] => boolean
                    [is_app_collection] => boolean
                )

            [primaryKey:protected] => id
            [keyType:protected] => int
            [incrementing] => 1
            [with:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [perPage:protected] => 15
            [exists] => 1
            [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            [attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Test
                )

            [original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Test           
                )

            [dates:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [dateFormat:protected] => 
            [appends:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [events:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [observables:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [touches:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [hidden:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [visible:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [guarded:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => *
                )

        )

    [resultsCount:protected] => 19
    [resultsProducts:protected] => 
    [cache:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [splitOption:protected] => 
    [context:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: plz post more codes about `$allFiles`

Comment: @TsaiKoga sure,  just added

Comment: what about `dd(get_class($allFiles))`? is `$files` from some model?